# Estimate for $\sum_{q=1}^{M}\frac{\varphi(q)}{q^{2}}$ Related to Bourgain Paper

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $N\gg 1$ be a large parameter, which I ultimately want to let tend to infinity. I am reading an old [paper](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.158/bourgain-restriction.pdf) of Bourgain, where he claims the lower bound (Equation 2.50, pg. 118)

$$\sum_{q=1}^{N^{1/2}-1}\sum_{{1\leq a < q}\atop{(a,q)=1}}\frac{N^{3}}{q^{2}}\geq c(\log N)N^{3}, \tag{1}$$

where $(a,q)$ denotes the GCD of $a$ and $q$ and $c>0$ is some absolute constant, the value of which I don't care and may change from line to line.

Using the following [lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate) for Euler's totient function $\varphi(n)$

$$\varphi(n)>\frac{n}{e^{\gamma}\log\log n + \frac{3}{\log\log n}} \tag{2}$$

and the PNT, I only know how to show that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=1}^{N^{1/2}-1}\sum_{{1\leq a < q}\atop{(a,q)=1}}\frac{N^{3}}{q^{2}}&\geq c\sum_{{1\leq q<N^{1/2}-1}\atop{q=\mathrm{prime}}}\frac{N^{3}}{q^{2}}\cdot q\\
&+c\sum_{{1\ll q<N^{1/2}-1}\atop{q\neq\mathrm{prime}}}\frac{N^{3}}{q^{2}}\cdot\frac{q}{e^{\gamma}\log\log q+\frac{3}{\log\log q}}\\
&\geq cN^{3}\log\log N \tag{3}
\end{align*}

If I knew the asymptotics of the series $\sum_{q=1}^{N^{1/2}-1}\frac{\varphi(q)}{q^{2}}$ or $\sum_{q=1}^{N^{1/2}-1}\frac{1}{\sigma(q)}$, where $\sigma$ is the divisor sum function, then my problem would be solved. However, I have been unable to find such information.

---

John M. has very kindly provided me with the necessary asymptotics. To see how to get that formula, first recall that $\varphi(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\frac{n}{d}$, where $\mu$ is the Mobius function, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}}=\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}$. Then

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^{2}}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\frac{n}{d}=\sum_{{q,d}\atop{qd\leq x}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}q}=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}}\sum_{q\leq\frac{x}{d}}\frac{1}{q} \tag{4}$$

Using the formula
$$\sum_{q\leq k}\frac{1}{k}=\log(k)+\gamma+\epsilon_{k},$$
where $\epsilon_{k}\sim\frac{1}{k}$, and $|\log(y)-\log([y])|=O(1/y)$, we see that

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{(4)}&=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{2}}[\log(x)-\log(d)+\gamma+O(\frac{1}{x/d})]\\
&=(\log(x)+\gamma)(\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}-\sum_{d>x}\frac{1}{d^{2}})-\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(d)\log(d)}{d^{2}}+\sum_{d>x}\frac{\mu(d)\log(d)}{d^{2}}+O(\frac{\log x}{x})\\
&=\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}(\log(x)+\gamma)-A+O(\frac{\log x}{x})
\end{align*}

Comment: @JohnM: I don't understand your comment. Equation 2.50 is supposed to be the lower bound obtained from the sum of Equation 2.49 over integers $1\leq q<N^{1/2}$, $1\leq a<q$ with $(a,q)=1$, and $0\leq b<q$. How is this different than what I wrote?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @JohnM: Basically, the answer to my question will be solved by knowing the asymptotics of the series $\sum_{q=1}^{N^{1/2}-1}\frac{\varphi(q)}{q^{2}}$. But I've been unable to find such a thing.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig I think the Dirichlet series for $\phi(q)/q^2$ is $\zeta(s+1)/\zeta(s+2)$, whose rightmost pole is at $s=0$ with residue $6/\pi^2$, so I would expect $\sum_{q=1}^{\sqrt{N}} \phi(q)/q^2$ to be asymptotic to $3/\pi^2 \ln N$.  Since $\phi(q)>0$ this implies a lower bound of the form $c \ln N$ for some universal $c>0$ (that is chosen small enough to account for small values of $N$).

Answer (score 2):

The lower bound you desire follows from my answer here answer: [Bounds on a sum of gcd's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326147/bounds-on-a-sum-of-gcds/326767#326767)

Specifically, from the asymptotic $$\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)=\frac{3}{\pi^2}x^2+O(x\log x),$$ we can use partial summation to show that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\log x+O(1).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{q \leq x} \frac{\phi(q)}{q^2} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}(\gamma + \log x) - A + O\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)$$
where $A$ is the constant
$$A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n) \log{n}}{n^2}$$
and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: Thanks, John; this looks great. What is this reference for this estimate?

Comment: Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory,* pg. 71, Ch 3, Exercise 6.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig : once you know $\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_n \varphi(n) n^{-s}$ you get that $F(s) = \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)} - \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(2)} = \sum_n (\varphi(n)-\frac{n}{\zeta(2)}) n^{-s}$ is holomorphic for $Re(s) > 1$ and with a little more work you get the kind of estimate John wrote